# Rasing a 401 in a custom authentication methoud for Django

Tags: python, django

I have my own custom authentication for Django, when a user fails (bad username and company) I need it to respond with a 401 and a message. At the moment I have tried a standard Exception which give me 500 and using `HttpResponse` which it does not accept.

```
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, request=None, **kwargs):

    if request:
        try:
            company = VendorToApplication.objects.get(request.company)
            user = AppUser.objects.get(email=username, company=company)

            if user.check_password(password):
                return user

        except AppUser.DoesNotExist:
            raise BadCompany()
```

If I try:

```
        except AppUser.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse("aa", status=401)
```

I get...

> 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'is_active'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) on this:

> Either way, authenticate should check the credentials it gets, and it should return a User object that matches those credentials, if the credentials are valid. **If they’re not valid, it should return None.**

Comment: If I return None it will continue to check other backends. raising an exception allows me to terminal it and stop from checking other backends. The problems comes in when the Django admin which does not check for company then grants them access - Bad!

Comment: So [disable the default backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS) if you do not need it, or replace it with a smarter backend (e.g. which subclasses the original) if you do.

Comment: Good idea, I could check to see if the user is staff or if the URL is /admin/ thanks